# Does ADFS 2.0 with WS-Federation support IdP-initiated SSO?

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs2.0, ws-federation

Does ADFS 2.0 with WS-Federation support IdP-initiated SSO? and if yes, how? I could not find the answer on the internet yet and if yes, could you please help me with a sample?

I configured a trust relation between the ADFS 2.0 (IdP) and my RP using a metadata configuration. Everything works fine in SP initiated SSO but I don't know how to configure the IdP initiated one.

I'm opening this link https://[SOEMTHING]/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx but it is showing an empty list with Signout button only.

What did I miss?
is it configured through the RP-metadata file only?

Answer (score 4):

There's no such thing as IDP-initiated-SSO in the WS-Federation standard, but ADFS 2.0 allows for so-called "smart links" that achieve relatively similar behavior as described in: http://community.office365.com/en-us/w/sso/358-using-smart-links-or-idp-initiated-authentication-with-office-365.aspx. Your RP (e.g. O365) needs to support that too.

Comment: Seems that IdP initiated SSO is supported by ADFS only with SAML2.

Comment: You can find the artice Hans mentioned here: https://web.archive.org/web/20140226110120/http://community.office365.com/en-us/wikis/sso/using-smart-links-or-idp-initiated-authentication-with-office-365.aspx This blog post is also usful: https://blog.kloud.com.au/2012/10/12/office-365-smart-links/